# On simplifying an inequality

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

Me and my friend have been stuck on this problem for some time now. The problem is as follows:

> Show that $$\Delta \cdot 2^{2\Delta} \geq 4n$$ $$ \implies \Delta \geq \frac12\log n - \frac12\log \log n + \frac12$$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

---

**Edit:**
Perhaps it'll be right to give some context to this question. Me and my friend are currently studying Chung et.al's paper [On induced subgraph of the cube](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316588900349). The aforementioned problem of ours comes at the very last step of their paper.

Here $\Delta$ denotes the maximum degree of the graph $G$, an induced subgraph of the $n$-dimensional hypercube graph $Q^n$.

Comment: Is it $$x\cdot 2^{2x}\geq 4n$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $n\ge 10^{0.1}$. Then $x>1$ and $\log(\log n) \ge -1$. Therefore

$$25^x>25x$$ $$10^{2x}>100(\frac{x}{4}2^{2x})\ge 100n$$ $$2x>\log n+2$$ 
$$2x>\log n-\log(\log n)+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

If there are no restrictions on $n$ other than $n\ge 1$, then the result is false.

Let $x=2$ and $n$ tend to 1 from above.